# boost time_duration total seconds calculation

Tags: c++, boost

I want to calculation the time difference in second between two timestamps which are in `boost::posix_time:ptime`. However, since timestamp contains up to microsecond, the result may come out that is not I expect.

```
boost::posix_time::time_period oPeriod(start, end);
int32_t iDuration = oPeriod.length().total_seconds();

printf("AAAA [%s], [%s], [%d]\n", boost::posix_time::to_iso_string(start).c_str(), boost::posix_time::to_iso_string(end).c_str(), iDuration);
```

output:

```
AAAA [20131030T232150.619049], [20131030T232152.558225], [1]
```

what I want is to truncate the the fraction of second and then calculate the difference. So the result above should be 2 instead of 1.

Is there way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No straightforward route as far as I know, you'll have to remove the `fractional_seconds()` from both `start` and `end` before doing the subtraction, i.e.

```
start -= start.fractional_seconds();
end -= end.fractional_seconds();
auto diff = end - start;
```

(NOTE: I'm assuming that `start` and `end` are `time_duration`, if they are `ptime`, then you'll have to get the time of day from them first...)